# Advanced Help Command on Discord.Py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, bots, discord.py

I know I'm new here, but I have a question for you:

What if you ever wanted to write a Discord bot in Python, with special cogs, and replace the default help command with this:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(self,ctx,*cog:str):
    """Gives you info on my cogs *and* their commands."""
    if not cog:
        halp=discord.Embed(title='Cog Listing and Uncatergorized Commands',
                           description='Use `!help *cog*` to find out more about them!')
        cogs_desc = ''
        for x in self.bot.cogs:
            cogs_desc += ('{} - {}'.format(x,self.bot.cogs[x].__doc__)+'\n')
        halp.add_field(name='Cogs',value=cogs_desc[0:len(cogs_desc)-1])
    else:
        halp=discord.Embed(title='{cog} Command Listing')
        for x in self.bot.cogs[cog]:
            halp.add_field(name=x,value=x.__doc__)

    await self.bot.whisper(embed=halp)
```

...and the command sends the info on your bot's cogs just fine, but refuses to give you info on a specific cog's commands and gives you this:

```
    Ignoring exception in command help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Coding/Python/AwesomeDiscordBot/cogs/info.py", line 49, in help
    for x in self.bot.cogs[cog]:
KeyError: ('Info',)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: ('Info',)
```

How would you fix it so that you can use your Discord bot's !help command to get info on cogs *and* their commands?

P.S. I'm using Python 3.5 on a Raspberry Pi, and I want to include uncatergorized commands in the main help embed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You **should not** just delete the default help command and make a command called help. You should subclass `commands.HelpCommand`.

Here is a useful tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96